# Is there a concat function in GQL?

Tags: gql

Is there a concat function in Google Query Language?

Given table X

```
FName   |LName
--------|------
Bob     |Smith
Larry   |Potts
```

Ask query:

```
Select Concat(FName, LName) from X
```

I would like:

```
BobSmith
LarryPotts
```

Any ideas on how to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate them manually aftewards:

```
query = GqlQuery(...)
for result in query:
    fullname = result.FName+result.LName
    # Do something with fullname
```